# StateProvider not updating with correct values

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I've been trying to use [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) for state management in a POC app, I have a screen with a text editing controller, I'm trying to check whether the text is empty for a textfield and enable/disable a button based on that logic. There seems to be an issue with my code since the button seems to always display the opposite status of what I'm trying to do. How can I fix this issue ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/models/task.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/reusable_widgets/app_bar.dart';

class TaskScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const TaskScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TaskScreenState createState() => TaskScreenState();
}

class TaskScreenState extends ConsumerState<TaskScreen> {
  DateTime? _selectedDate;
  static final TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  var textProvider = StateProvider((_) => _titleController.text.isNotEmpty);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool value = ref.watch(textProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: const AppBarWrapper(
        title: "To-Do List",
      ),
      body: Stack(children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _titleController,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  ref.read(textProvider.state).state = val.isEmpty;
                },
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Title"),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 14,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _descriptionController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Description"),
                minLines: 3,
                maxLines: 5,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 150,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  title: Text(
                    _selectedDate?.toString() ?? 'No Date',
                  ),
                  onTap: () async {
                    _selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                      lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 365)),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: value
                ? () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(Task(
                        title: _titleController.text,
                        description: _descriptionController.text.isNotEmpty
                            ? _descriptionController.text
                            : null,
                        date: _selectedDate));
                  }
                : null,
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.done,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change  `ref.read(textProvider.state).state = val.isEmpty;` to `ref.read(textProvider.notifier).state = val.isEmpty;`. It should help you